# Neural network training and validation accuracy stuck at 50% and 48% respectively, loss not decreasing after that and score turns out bad

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, multiclass-classification

i've been working on a multiclass classification neural network model on Rstudio with KERAS and Tensorflow where i am trying to achieve at least 70 to 80% accuracy because i had tried tuning the hyperparameters to increase the accuracy but no matter how much that i had tuned on number of epochs, number of layers, or even changing on batch size, both training and validation accuracy doesn't seem to be increasing and training and validation loss stuck at a certain loss value.

this is my model that im working on:

```
        model %>%
          layer_dense(units = 28, activation = 'relu',input_shape = c(24), kernel_regularizer = regularizer_l2(0.0001))%>%
          layer_dropout(0.01)%>%
          layer_dense(units = 28, activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer = regularizer_l2(0.0001))%>%
          layer_dropout(0.01)%>%
          layer_dense(units = 28, activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer = regularizer_l2(0.0001))%>%
          layer_dropout(0.01)%>%
          layer_dense(units = 28, activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer = regularizer_l2(0.0001))%>%
          layer_dropout(0.01)%>%
          layer_dense(units = 28, activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer = regularizer_l2(0.0001))%>%
          layer_dropout(0.01)%>%
          layer_dense(units = 28, activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer = regularizer_l2(0.0001))%>%
          layer_dropout(0.01)%>%
          layer_dense(units = 8, activation = 'softmax', kernel_regularizer = regularizer_l2(0.0001))
    model %>%
      compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'Adam', metrics = 'accuracy')
    history <- model%>%
      fit(training, trainlabels, epoch = 12000, batch_size = 64, validation_split = 0.2, shuffle = TRUE )
```

and this is the epoch progression:

```
Epoch 11900/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3010 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 1.3180 - val_accuracy: 0.4823
Epoch 11901/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3008 - accuracy: 0.5007 - val_loss: 1.3326 - val_accuracy: 0.4694
Epoch 11902/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2999 - accuracy: 0.4961 - val_loss: 1.3188 - val_accuracy: 0.4929
Epoch 11903/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 1.2983 - accuracy: 0.4945 - val_loss: 1.3154 - val_accuracy: 0.4860
Epoch 11904/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3040 - accuracy: 0.4973 - val_loss: 1.3030 - val_accuracy: 0.4887
Epoch 11905/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2904 - accuracy: 0.5021 - val_loss: 1.3125 - val_accuracy: 0.4896
Epoch 11906/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2956 - accuracy: 0.4947 - val_loss: 1.3187 - val_accuracy: 0.4814
Epoch 11907/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3049 - accuracy: 0.4953 - val_loss: 1.3355 - val_accuracy: 0.4727
Epoch 11908/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2978 - accuracy: 0.5025 - val_loss: 1.3250 - val_accuracy: 0.4864
Epoch 11909/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2958 - accuracy: 0.4979 - val_loss: 1.3273 - val_accuracy: 0.4850
Epoch 11910/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2991 - accuracy: 0.4994 - val_loss: 1.3150 - val_accuracy: 0.4864
Epoch 11911/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3040 - accuracy: 0.5006 - val_loss: 1.3458 - val_accuracy: 0.4775
Epoch 11912/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3066 - accuracy: 0.4969 - val_loss: 1.3051 - val_accuracy: 0.4842
Epoch 11913/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3029 - accuracy: 0.4988 - val_loss: 1.3239 - val_accuracy: 0.4885
Epoch 11914/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2890 - accuracy: 0.5040 - val_loss: 1.3321 - val_accuracy: 0.4719
Epoch 11915/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2987 - accuracy: 0.4969 - val_loss: 1.3495 - val_accuracy: 0.4708
Epoch 11916/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 1.2952 - accuracy: 0.4981 - val_loss: 1.3177 - val_accuracy: 0.4779
Epoch 11917/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2980 - accuracy: 0.4977 - val_loss: 1.3104 - val_accuracy: 0.4904
Epoch 11918/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2985 - accuracy: 0.4990 - val_loss: 1.3220 - val_accuracy: 0.4850
Epoch 11919/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2940 - accuracy: 0.4988 - val_loss: 1.2994 - val_accuracy: 0.4898
Epoch 11920/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3000 - accuracy: 0.5001 - val_loss: 1.3183 - val_accuracy: 0.4865
Epoch 11921/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2957 - accuracy: 0.4991 - val_loss: 1.3215 - val_accuracy: 0.4841
Epoch 11922/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2930 - accuracy: 0.5024 - val_loss: 1.3205 - val_accuracy: 0.4823
Epoch 11923/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3026 - accuracy: 0.4972 - val_loss: 1.3034 - val_accuracy: 0.4864
Epoch 11924/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2943 - accuracy: 0.4995 - val_loss: 1.3423 - val_accuracy: 0.4812
Epoch 11925/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3033 - accuracy: 0.4998 - val_loss: 1.3082 - val_accuracy: 0.4875
Epoch 11926/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3032 - accuracy: 0.4977 - val_loss: 1.3241 - val_accuracy: 0.4806
Epoch 11927/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2988 - accuracy: 0.4975 - val_loss: 1.3132 - val_accuracy: 0.4827
Epoch 11928/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3064 - accuracy: 0.4952 - val_loss: 1.3422 - val_accuracy: 0.4794
Epoch 11929/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2988 - accuracy: 0.4953 - val_loss: 1.3279 - val_accuracy: 0.4892
Epoch 11930/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3015 - accuracy: 0.4994 - val_loss: 1.3181 - val_accuracy: 0.4779
Epoch 11931/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2967 - accuracy: 0.4990 - val_loss: 1.3400 - val_accuracy: 0.4858
Epoch 11932/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3042 - accuracy: 0.4968 - val_loss: 1.3152 - val_accuracy: 0.4867
Epoch 11933/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3052 - accuracy: 0.4958 - val_loss: 1.3246 - val_accuracy: 0.4864
Epoch 11934/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2974 - accuracy: 0.4971 - val_loss: 1.3155 - val_accuracy: 0.4841
Epoch 11935/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2999 - accuracy: 0.4975 - val_loss: 1.3182 - val_accuracy: 0.4940
Epoch 11936/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3013 - accuracy: 0.5006 - val_loss: 1.3594 - val_accuracy: 0.4660
Epoch 11937/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2975 - accuracy: 0.4955 - val_loss: 1.3295 - val_accuracy: 0.4779
Epoch 11938/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2925 - accuracy: 0.4983 - val_loss: 1.3597 - val_accuracy: 0.4731
Epoch 11939/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3017 - accuracy: 0.4991 - val_loss: 1.3321 - val_accuracy: 0.4854
Epoch 11940/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 1.2992 - accuracy: 0.4985 - val_loss: 1.3251 - val_accuracy: 0.4831
Epoch 11941/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3023 - accuracy: 0.4955 - val_loss: 1.3430 - val_accuracy: 0.4781
Epoch 11942/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2984 - accuracy: 0.5010 - val_loss: 1.3113 - val_accuracy: 0.4933
Epoch 11943/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3000 - accuracy: 0.4972 - val_loss: 1.3267 - val_accuracy: 0.4783
Epoch 11944/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2963 - accuracy: 0.4989 - val_loss: 1.3713 - val_accuracy: 0.4671
Epoch 11945/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3088 - accuracy: 0.4945 - val_loss: 1.3122 - val_accuracy: 0.4862
Epoch 11946/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3062 - accuracy: 0.4965 - val_loss: 1.3142 - val_accuracy: 0.4802
Epoch 11947/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3005 - accuracy: 0.4993 - val_loss: 1.3279 - val_accuracy: 0.4852
Epoch 11948/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3069 - accuracy: 0.4953 - val_loss: 1.3111 - val_accuracy: 0.4873
Epoch 11949/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3035 - accuracy: 0.4966 - val_loss: 1.3289 - val_accuracy: 0.4867
Epoch 11950/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3024 - accuracy: 0.4963 - val_loss: 1.3416 - val_accuracy: 0.4816
Epoch 11951/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2966 - accuracy: 0.5009 - val_loss: 1.3485 - val_accuracy: 0.4727
Epoch 11952/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2989 - accuracy: 0.4978 - val_loss: 1.3178 - val_accuracy: 0.4829
Epoch 11953/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2961 - accuracy: 0.4982 - val_loss: 1.3267 - val_accuracy: 0.4785
Epoch 11954/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3022 - accuracy: 0.4989 - val_loss: 1.3302 - val_accuracy: 0.4823
Epoch 11955/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2982 - accuracy: 0.4957 - val_loss: 1.3090 - val_accuracy: 0.4839
Epoch 11956/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2947 - accuracy: 0.5020 - val_loss: 1.3337 - val_accuracy: 0.4791
Epoch 11957/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2881 - accuracy: 0.4985 - val_loss: 1.3179 - val_accuracy: 0.4817
Epoch 11958/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2929 - accuracy: 0.5023 - val_loss: 1.3211 - val_accuracy: 0.4792
Epoch 11959/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2977 - accuracy: 0.4980 - val_loss: 1.3222 - val_accuracy: 0.4800
Epoch 11960/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2992 - accuracy: 0.4972 - val_loss: 1.3390 - val_accuracy: 0.4769
Epoch 11961/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3014 - accuracy: 0.5003 - val_loss: 1.3238 - val_accuracy: 0.4856
Epoch 11962/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3005 - accuracy: 0.4960 - val_loss: 1.3300 - val_accuracy: 0.4789
Epoch 11963/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3025 - accuracy: 0.4987 - val_loss: 1.3037 - val_accuracy: 0.4802
Epoch 11964/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2983 - accuracy: 0.4969 - val_loss: 1.3381 - val_accuracy: 0.4792
Epoch 11965/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 1.2969 - accuracy: 0.4982 - val_loss: 1.3007 - val_accuracy: 0.4871
Epoch 11966/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3018 - accuracy: 0.4967 - val_loss: 1.3417 - val_accuracy: 0.4837
Epoch 11967/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2987 - accuracy: 0.4970 - val_loss: 1.3202 - val_accuracy: 0.4860
Epoch 11968/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2931 - accuracy: 0.5005 - val_loss: 1.3095 - val_accuracy: 0.4871
Epoch 11969/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2977 - accuracy: 0.4967 - val_loss: 1.3038 - val_accuracy: 0.4860
Epoch 11970/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2956 - accuracy: 0.4974 - val_loss: 1.3440 - val_accuracy: 0.4833
Epoch 11971/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3007 - accuracy: 0.5018 - val_loss: 1.3378 - val_accuracy: 0.4777
Epoch 11972/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2973 - accuracy: 0.4972 - val_loss: 1.3173 - val_accuracy: 0.4848
Epoch 11973/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2901 - accuracy: 0.4974 - val_loss: 1.3145 - val_accuracy: 0.4814
Epoch 11974/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2952 - accuracy: 0.4995 - val_loss: 1.3260 - val_accuracy: 0.4850
Epoch 11975/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2976 - accuracy: 0.4982 - val_loss: 1.3476 - val_accuracy: 0.4677
Epoch 11976/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2979 - accuracy: 0.5014 - val_loss: 1.3270 - val_accuracy: 0.4754
Epoch 11977/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2991 - accuracy: 0.5001 - val_loss: 1.3295 - val_accuracy: 0.4779
Epoch 11978/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2974 - accuracy: 0.4973 - val_loss: 1.3053 - val_accuracy: 0.4931
Epoch 11979/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2963 - accuracy: 0.4958 - val_loss: 1.3156 - val_accuracy: 0.4919
Epoch 11980/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2962 - accuracy: 0.5031 - val_loss: 1.3201 - val_accuracy: 0.4791
Epoch 11981/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2908 - accuracy: 0.4987 - val_loss: 1.3110 - val_accuracy: 0.4881
Epoch 11982/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3048 - accuracy: 0.4988 - val_loss: 1.3283 - val_accuracy: 0.4798
Epoch 11983/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3063 - accuracy: 0.4973 - val_loss: 1.3170 - val_accuracy: 0.4821
Epoch 11984/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3019 - accuracy: 0.4958 - val_loss: 1.3084 - val_accuracy: 0.4835
Epoch 11985/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2981 - accuracy: 0.4977 - val_loss: 1.3381 - val_accuracy: 0.4696
Epoch 11986/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3006 - accuracy: 0.4969 - val_loss: 1.3087 - val_accuracy: 0.4827
Epoch 11987/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3093 - accuracy: 0.4911 - val_loss: 1.3154 - val_accuracy: 0.4889
Epoch 11988/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2981 - accuracy: 0.5002 - val_loss: 1.3164 - val_accuracy: 0.4827
Epoch 11989/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3022 - accuracy: 0.4938 - val_loss: 1.3202 - val_accuracy: 0.4808
Epoch 11990/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 1.2953 - accuracy: 0.4960 - val_loss: 1.3113 - val_accuracy: 0.4908
Epoch 11991/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2984 - accuracy: 0.4963 - val_loss: 1.3170 - val_accuracy: 0.4839
Epoch 11992/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2917 - accuracy: 0.5012 - val_loss: 1.3479 - val_accuracy: 0.4769
Epoch 11993/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3008 - accuracy: 0.4955 - val_loss: 1.3423 - val_accuracy: 0.4833
Epoch 11994/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3007 - accuracy: 0.4984 - val_loss: 1.3168 - val_accuracy: 0.4850
Epoch 11995/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3020 - accuracy: 0.4966 - val_loss: 1.3266 - val_accuracy: 0.4754
Epoch 11996/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2979 - accuracy: 0.4993 - val_loss: 1.3091 - val_accuracy: 0.4808
Epoch 11997/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2962 - accuracy: 0.5026 - val_loss: 1.3339 - val_accuracy: 0.4792
Epoch 11998/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3100 - accuracy: 0.4973 - val_loss: 1.3150 - val_accuracy: 0.4833
Epoch 11999/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3036 - accuracy: 0.4978 - val_loss: 1.3295 - val_accuracy: 0.4819
Epoch 12000/12000
326/326 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.2901 - accuracy: 0.5007 - val_loss: 1.3061 - val_accuracy: 0.4802
```

but after all the trainings, the scores concludes

```
loss: 1.3303 - accuracy: 0.4683
```

the accuracy and the loss is as shown below:

[accuracy of the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jzz9.png)

[loss of the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asbnn.png)

[Loss and Accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLjB4.png)

am i underfitting the training model?? how can i actually increase the accuracy and letting the model to learn something?

Comment: What's the size of your data? Is it balanced? Is this image data? Have you tried lowering the learning rate?

Comment: @Djinn the size of the data is 28902 to be exact, and is not an image data; is a data containing probability of the companies predicting a Team outcome from a match. eg, if MU (HomeTeam) win against Chelsea (AwayTeam), company A has 0.45 of probability predicting MU wins, while company B has 0.43 of probability predicting MU wins. so from there, we know that Company A has the highest probability. the model should know that the company A is the company that has highest probability. I tried lowering the learning rate but doesnt seem to change anything

Comment: @Djinn the splitting i put 0.9 for training and 0.1 for test.

Comment: Do you have to only use Dense layers? Can you also use convolutional layers?

Comment: i never thought of using convolutional layers because i always thought that it mainly used on images classifications, text classifcations and all. Hence, the reason of using only dense layers

Comment: I would try removing some of the dense layers and using convolutional layers at the start, then seeing how it affects performance.

Comment: To add to this, using keras hyper parameter tuning can often help with these problems. Check out the docs here: https://keras.io/keras_tuner/